How to parse a JSON string with list?
I need to parse the below json string(single json string as value)  which contains the list in column in pyspark dataframe.
detailscolumn
{"licence":"1.0","date":1729768924852,"Students":[{"city":"boston","code":null,"Details":{"refnumber":2,"refcolumn":9},"More    Details":{"rolenum":"21","name":null,"joiningdate":null}},{"city":"Cal","code":null,"Details":{"refnumber":3,"refcolumn":10},"More  Details":{"rolenum":"22","name":null,"joiningdate":null}},{"city":"los","code":null,"Details":{"refnumber":4,"refcolumn":11},"More  Details":{"rolenum":"23","name":null,"joiningdate":null}},{"city":"san","code":null,"Details":{"refnumber":5,"refcolumn":12},"More  Details":{"rolenum":"24","name":null,"joiningdate":null}}]}

df.show()
df:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
detailscolumn: string
i am expecting to get the result like this after parsing the json string column in pyspark dataframe
enter image description here
Thanks for the help in advance.

Welcome to SO! A good starting point are the PySpark docs. Feel free to post any questions that are left afterwards. And please: do not post images of your data.

Instead of image , please input the data to help check the json structure.
here is the code, which should give you the expected output
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# Create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("JSON_to_DataFrame").getOrCreate()

# Read the JSON data into a DataFrame
df = spark.read.json("your_json_file.json")

# Flatten the nested structure using a higher-order function
df = df.withColumn("Students", F.explode("Students")) \
    .select(
        "licence",
        "date",
        "Students.city",
        "Students.code",
        "Students.Details.refnumber",
        "Students.Details.refcolumn",
        "Students.More Details.rolenum",
        "Students.More Details.name",
        "Students.More Details.joiningdate"
    )

# Rename columns as needed
df = df.withColumnRenamed("Students.city", "city") \
    .withColumnRenamed("Students.code", "code") \
    .withColumnRenamed("Students.Details.refnumber", "refnumber") \
    .withColumnRenamed("Students.Details.refcolumn", "refcolumn") \
    .withColumnRenamed("Students.More Details.rolenum", "rolenum") \
    .withColumnRenamed("Students.More Details.name", "name") \
    .withColumnRenamed("Students.More Details.joiningdate", "joiningdate")

# Show the DataFrame
df.show()


Cannot resolve "explode(details)" due to data type mismatch: Parameter 1 requires the ("ARRAY" or "MAP") type, however "details" has the type "STRING"

please note, above json string is in one of the column and not in the json file

I got a downvote, unsure if I should edit my answer
